# Erro: Cadastrando ? no lugar de caractere especial somente usando o navegador

Tags: c#, oracle, codificação-de-caracteres, ado.net, utf-8

Estou tendo um problema na hora de salvar os dados no meu banco de dados ORACLE.

Ao utilizar minha aplicação para efetuar o preenchimento dos campos e cadastrar uma string, os caracteres especiais como acentos por exemplo são substituídos por uma **?** no banco de dados

O detalhe é que se pego a mesma consulta e faço pelo SQL DEVELOPER ele cadastra normalmente qualquer caractere especial.

Minha aplicação é feita em C#, com as páginas utilizando Razor (cshtml). O charset do html é UTF-8.

Não sei como verificar o charset do banco, pois sou bem iniciante em ORACLE.

Idéias sobre o que pode estar causando isso?

Código na aplicação:

```
comand.CommandText = "UPDATE TB_EBITDA SET TXT_OBSERVACAO = '" + txt_observacao + "' WHERE COD_CONFIGURACAO = " + codigo + "";
dataReader = comand.ExecuteReader();
dataReader.Read();
```

Código gerado, peguei através do debug e colei no SQL Developer:

```
UPDATE TB_EBITDA SET TXT_OBSERVACAO = 'Observacão' WHERE COD_CONFIGURACAO = 5
```

Comment: Pode por favor passar o código utilizado para inserir os dados no banco?

Comment: Não sei se é muito relevante, mas ta aí. "Observação" escrevi sem cedilha mesmo. Mas grava "Observac?o"

Comment: Você não está usando parâmetros para executar seu comando. O correto seria seu `CommandText` ter a declaração de parâmetro e especificar o unicode no parâmetro.

Comment: Consegue dar um exemplo?

Comment: Vou tentar responder.

Comment: Isso não seria uma configuração do próprio banco?
Pois seu command parece estar certinho.
Dê uma olhada nesse link(http://eltzti.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/configuracao-apex-oracle-xe-characterset/) e se possível faça as alterações.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente o problema é na (falta de) parametrização da sua sentença. Sem esta parametrização, nada garante que você esteja executando uma sentença aderente ao padrão Unicode.

Eu escreveria seu código da seguinte forma:

```
comand.CommandText = "UPDATE TB_EBITDA SET TXT_OBSERVACAO = :txt_observacao WHERE COD_CONFIGURACAO = " + codigo + "";

IDbDataParameter param = comand.CreateParameter()
param.DbType = DbType.AnsiString;
param.ParameterName = "txt_observacao";
param.Value = txt_observacao;

comand.Parameters.Add(param);
dataReader = comand.ExecuteReader();
dataReader.Read();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, sua resposta foi a alavanca para eu conseguir uma solução. Me permite editar sua resposta e colocar o código que funcionou para mim? Assim eu marco a sua como correta.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Sim, claro! Fique à vontade.